A question of energy creation/transfer
A solid m³ of granite traveling at 1kph is dropped into a large body of water resulting in an initial wave (and smaller subsequent waves).
The expanding initial wave created, is the reason for my question.
Wouldn’t the cumulative energy (collected in the round) be greater than the energy spent to lift the granite above the water high enough for a drop rate, at time of impact, of 1kph?

If we take the lake surface as the reference level for gravitational potential, then the block's continues to lose potential energy and its p.e. becomes negative as it sinks beneath the lake surface. Is that what you're asking? When you "collect" the energy "in the round", what forms of energy are you collecting? Just water waves? Or also sound waves? G.p.e. of water displaced above the initial surface level?

Thank you…I need to be more specific.  To answer your question, yes I’m only interested to know if the energy of the water wave again, collected and measured using a round collection method, adds up to more than the lift energy used.

Welcome Kole KInkade to Physics Stack Exchange. Please explain why 1 kph is chosen. Why not 0 kph? Since any any any excess energy relative to the granite's original height at above the water level comes from the granite falling beneath the water's surface, the initial height of the granite might as well be set to zero.  The total gravitational energy available to the granite when falling is relative to the bottom of the water, not its surface.

The law of conservation of energy tells us that the energy in the waves can be at most equal to the difference in potential energy between the rock in its initial position and the rock in its final position (assuming its initial and final speeds are both zero).
If the waves contained more energy than this then it would in principle be possible to extract this energy from the waves and use it to raise the rock to a higher position, drop it again - and so create a perpetual motion machine.

Almost certainly not. From conservation of energy, we know that the total energy released by dropping the block is equal to the potential energy given up by the block.
But the water waves are not the only energy released. There is also sound when the block strikes the water, heat from the internal friction in the air and water around the block, and also some energy used to lift a portion of the water that is raised above the original surface level of the water.
